# How to configure sonatype nexus to allow sbt plugins?

Tags: sbt, nexus, sbt-plugin

When publishing our plugin we got this

```
[info] Done packaging.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:publish for the full output.
[error] (*:publish) java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/foo/foo-sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-sbt-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom failed with status code 400: Invalid path for a Maven 2 repository
```

We set up the plugin using

```
sbtPlugin := true
publishMavenStyle := true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was fixed by setting the repository `Layout Policy` to `permissive` in the nexus admin.

http://nexus.mycompany.com/#admin/repository/repositories:maven-releases
http://nexus.mycompany.com/#admin/repository/repositories:maven-snapshots

Comment: I just spent six hours trying to find this issue. Thanks for documenting it!