# SBT publish failing due Maven2 path restrictions

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sbt-plugin

Our company uses a Maven repository to publish/consume shared Scala code. We are attempting to publish an SBT plugin to that repository but are getting the following error:

```
[error] java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL https://<secret_internal_url>/swagger-merger_2.12_1.0/0.1.7-SNAPSHOT/swagger-merger-0.1.7-SNAPSHOT.pom failed with status code 400: Invalid path for a Maven 2 repository
```

**I replaced the beginning of the actual url with secret_internal_url since I'm not allowed to disclose that domain**

I believe this issue is due to the `_1.0` portion of the url not conforming to the rules around Maven naming conventions. Our team is not allowed to change the [layout policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991268/how-to-configure-sonatype-nexus-to-allow-sbt-plugins) of the repo, so I believe my only option is to strip off the `_1.0` portion from the URL.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there an SBT setting that allows not including that `_1.0` in the URL?
2. Is this `_1.0` portion only present when publishing sbt plugins? We don't see this appended into the url on other non-plugin libraries when we publish